# Table cell only updates when I select it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm making an iOS app which uses a table, and each cell contains two labels and a custom view I made called `ColourCircle`. `ColourCircle` has a property called `fill: UIColor` and I've overridden the `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` function to draw a circle of that colour.

The cells' data are loaded from an array: `data: [(String, Double)]`, using the view controller as both the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`.

In `viewWillAppear` I've written:

```
guard let fetchedData = getArtistData() else {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "data-error", sender: nil)
    return
}

chart.load(data: fetchedData)
data = fetchedData
table.reloadData()
table.setNeedsLayout()

table.isHidden = false
chart.isHidden = false
activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
```

And, in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` I've written:

```
let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "artist cell") as! ArtistCell
let name = data[indexPath.row].0

if let proportion = chart.getPercentage(of: name) {
    let percentage = proportion * 100
    cell.name.text = name
    cell.percentage.text = "\(round(percentage * 10) / 10)%" // rounded to 2 d.p.
    cell.colour.fill = chart.colour(for: name)!
}

return cell
```

When I run my app, the visible cells (i.e. which are on the screen) work perfectly, and the `ColourCircle` views display the correct colour. When I scroll down, bringing new cells into view, the new cells don't have the correct colour, but instead use the colours from the previously loaded cells, in order.

For example, say the first two cells in the table are red and blue, then the first two which load when I scroll down will also be red and blue, in that order. The same thing happens when I scroll up, re-loading the previous cells.

When I select these cells, however, they change to the correct colour. Then, when unloaded and loaded again, they will stay the correct colour *unless I've fixed one of the cells further up (by selecting them)*, in which case they will change to the colours of the ones I fixed.

It seems like it's something to do with reusing the cells, although I can't quite work out how to fix it.

EDIT: Here's the code for my `ArtistCell` class:

```
class ArtistCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var colour: ColourCircle!
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var percentage: UILabel!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according this: `let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "artist cell") as! ArtistCell` - all cells are reusable. Use prepareForReuse() method, to prepare cell to reuse and clean up they content.

Comment: Not sure if I did it correctly, but I added `cell.prepareForReuse()` just under `let cell = ...`, and I still get the same problem.

Comment: you need to implement this method inside Cell's class, and remove changeable content. for more details add some code of cell's class.

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: implement in it prepare for reuse and clear current color and add new